# Elm - Turn Msg into Cmd Msg

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

I'm trying to modify a simple app from the [elm-lang tutorial](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/http.html) to first update the model, then trigger another update.

```
update msg model =
  case msg of
    MorePlease ->
      (model, getRandomGif model.topic)

    NewGif (Ok newUrl) ->
      ( { model | gifUrl = newUrl }, Cmd.none)

    NewGif (Err _) ->
      (model, Cmd.none)

    -- my addition
    NewTopic newTopic ->
      ({ model | topic = newTopic}, MorePlease)
```

This fails in the compiler because the NewTopic branch:

```
The 3rd branch has this type:

( { gifUrl : String, topic : String }, Cmd Msg )

But the 4th is:

( { gifUrl : String, topic : String }, Msg )
```

So my Msg needs to be type Cmd Msg. How can I turn" my Msg into a Cmd Msg?

*note: I recognize there is a simpler way to make this change, but I'm trying to understand Elm more fundamentally*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is really no need to turn `Msg` into a `Cmd Msg`. Remember that `update` is just a function, so you can call it recursively.

Your `NewTopic` case handler can be simplified to this:

```elm
NewTopic newTopic ->
    update MorePlease { model | topic = newTopic}
```

If you really truly wanted the Elm Architecture to fire off a Cmd for this scenario, you could do a simple `map` of `Cmd.none` to your desired `Msg`:

```elm
NewTopic newTopic ->
    ({ model | topic = newTopic}, Cmd.map (always MorePlease) Cmd.none)
```

(not actually recommended)

Comment: Thank you. This is an easier way to solve the problem. I still wonder, would I ever need to "cast" a `Msg` to a `Cmd Msg`? And how would I if I did?

Comment: @ChadGilbert: Could you elaborate a bit more why you would not recommend the second approach by firing new `Msg`?

Comment: Returning a `Cmd` will cause another cycle of the Elm Architecture lifecycle, so you're really just spending extra CPU cycles that you don't need to waste if it's just to fire off another Msg. There may be reasons you want to force another event cycle (like animation or other view updates, but even those require extra code). For the most part, forcing an unnecessary `Cmd`, IMO, feels like it's missing the underlying nature of the `update` function as being a function, and misunderstanding the event cycle.

Comment: Is there a possibility to pass some argument with the `MorePlease` message?

Comment: Yes, anything that results in a `Msg` can be used. E.g. `Cmd.map (always (SomethingElse param1 param2)) Cmd.none`

Comment: I was having a similar issue understanding this fundamentally.  I had split update into multiple functions and selected them based on a union type.  Once a user logs in, the type changes and a new update function will then be used.  I have some data that can be refreshed and I want it to be refreshed on login automatically so I was trying to send the Refresh message through the event system.

What I really needed to do was simply use the function that generates the command in the other update function which I had helpfully named refresh but failed to realize I could use to refresh the state.

Comment: Using `Cmd.map` seems to no longer work in 0.19. `Task.perform`, as @Deimos suggests below does.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following function:

```hs
run : msg -> Cmd msg
run m =
    Task.perform (always m) (Task.succeed ())
```

Your code would then turn into:

```hs
NewTopic newTopic ->
      ({ model | topic = newTopic}, run MorePlease)
```

Comment: Provide the explanation for your answer.

Comment: My message had a parameter, so the syntax was different, but using `Task.perform` worked for me when `Cmd.map` as shown in the accepted answer did not.

Comment: Works great (elm 0.19.1) ! Nice helper function, makes the code cleaner than inlining.