# How to "generate" own commands in simple application

Tags: elm

As a learning example for elm I want to create a simple snake game with the elm architecture.

Here is the full code so far:
https://gist.github.com/DanEEStar/b11509514d72eaafb640378fc7c93b44

A part of the program is a `UpdateWorld` message which gets generated by a button click and a `updateWorld` function which is called when the user presses the space key.

This leads to the following compiling and working code (snippets form the full code):

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateWorld ->
            ( updateWorld model, Cmd.none )

        KeyPress keyCode ->
            ( handleInput keyCode model, Cmd.none )


handleInput : Int -> Model -> Model
handleInput keyCode model =
    case Char.fromCode keyCode of
        ' ' ->
            updateWorld model

        _ ->
            model


updateWorld : Model -> Model
updateWorld model =
    { model | snake = updateSnake model.snake }


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Keyboard.presses KeyPress


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        -- here I can simply tell `onClick` to generate the `UpdateWorld` command
        [ button [ onClick UpdateWorld ] [ text "tick" ]
        ]
```

In this code snippets it is very clear that the `onClick` event generates the `UpdateWorld` command.
But in the `handleInput` function I have to "manually" call the `updateWorld` function.

What I would rather do is "generate" a new `UpdateWorld` command from my `handleInput` function. I think this would clarify the code. Something like:

```
handleInput keyCode =
    case Char.fromCode keyCode of
        ' ' ->
            -- how can I generate this command in my code
            UpdateWorld
```

How could I do this?

Is this even a good idea, or what would be a better pattern?

Answer (score 6):

Recall that `update` is just a function, which means you can call it recursively.

Consider changing the signature of `handleInput` to also return a `(Model, Cmd Msg)`, just like the `update` function:

```elm
handleInput : Int -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
handleInput keyCode model =
    case Char.fromCode keyCode of
        ' ' ->
            update UpdateWorld model
        'a' ->
            { model | snake = changeSnakeDirection model.snake West } ! []
        ...
```

You can get rid of the `updateWorld` function and move that code to the `UpdateWorld` message handler:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateWorld ->
            ( { model | snake = updateSnake model.snake }, Cmd.none )

        ChangeDirection newDirection ->
            ( { model | snake = changeSnakeDirection model.snake newDirection }, Cmd.none )

        KeyPress keyCode ->
            handleInput keyCode model
```

Comment: Thanks, this exactly solves my problem. I was looking into the wrong corner.

Comment: I have to take away the acceptance flag. After thinking some more about the problem I am still interested in the original question...

Comment: I stumbled into this answer of you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703561/669561.
This seems to be the same problem I have?!

Comment: Yes, as explained in that answer, while it is possible to fire off another `Cmd` for a specific `Msg`, you can/should stick with just calling `update` recursively unless you have an explicit reason for wanting to go through another Elm Architecture event cycle.